# Stack two divs LTR-horizontally when 2nd div may have loooong strings

Tags: html, css

Use-case seems to be trivial, but I could not make it work as need. I need to position 2nd div with all its content at the right side of the 1st div. When string is long enough it wraps to the second line with all combinations of the CSS attributes I've imagined to try:
[image: Wrong behaviour]

Notes:

- I do not know height of the content of these div and therefore cannot set fixed height to them as well as to the parent/container
- I can set fixed with to 1st div and actually want it to take the whole left part (from top to bottom)
- Actually, the thing i want is 'plain old' horizontal table with two cells, but without < table > tags.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdXrv/) and sample text I've tried. Typical solution with floats work well while 2nd div does not contain long strings:

HTML

```
<div class="container1 clearfix"><div>
        <p>first 1</p>
        <p>first 2</p>
    </div><div>
        <p>second 1</p>
        <p>second 2</p>
        <p>second second second second second second second second second second second second </p>
        <p>second 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after { display: table; content: " "; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

div { outline: 1px solid red; } 
div > div:nth-child(1) { outline: 1px solid green; } 
div > div:nth-child(2) { outline: 1px solid orange; } 


.container1 { overflow: hidden; }
.container1 > div { float: left; height: 100%; /* display: inline-block; */}
.container1 > div:nth-child(1) { width: 80px; } 
.container1 > div:nth-child(2) { }
```

Comment: is it ok to let a long line of text wrap to the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the `display:table-cell` rule on those divs:

```
.container1 > div {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TdXrv/1/)**

Comment: Nevertheless using 'table-like' css is discouraged' (do not know why) this appears to be the most straightforward solution, event height: 100% is not needed. Accepting this one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this might be a solution:

CSS:

```
.first-div {
  float: left; 
  width: 80px;
}

.second-div {
  margin-left: 81px;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

The `margin-left` on the second div accounts for the width of the first div plus the border allowing the second div to adjust its content to fit the available space as the screen resizes.

HTML:

```
<div class="container1">
  <div class="first-div">
    <p>first 1</p>
    <p>first 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="second-div">
    <p>second 1</p>
    <p>second 2</p>
    <p>second second second second second second second second second second second second</p>
    <p>second 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```